# Show the following f is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{|x|\log{(\frac{1}{|x|}})^2} & |x| \le 1/2 \\
      0 &\text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$

I want to show that $f(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable. First, by additivity of the integral, I get that

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\, dx = \int_{[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]} \frac{1}{|x|\log{(\frac{1}{|x|}})^2 }\, dx$$

From here, I've tried getting different approximations, but I've failed. I'm not sure how to deal with the undefined value at $x=0$ and the asymptotes at $x=1$ and $x=-1$.
Any ideas how to deal with these points?

Comment: The function has an antiderivative.  Try manipulating $\frac{1}{\log x}.$

Comment: You don't mean $\log{(\frac{1}{|x|}})^2,$ you mean $(\log{\frac{1}{|x|}})^2,$ right?

Comment: Right, I mean the latter expression

Answer (score 0):

Hint: That integral equals

$$2\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}\,dx.$$ Let $u=\ln x.$

Comment: Shouldn't there be $\frac{1}{x}$ in the logarithm?

Comment: It doesn't matter: $\ln (1/x)= - \ln x$ so when you square, you get what I have.